# Edit/Rename Key Names in .json dictionary

Tags: python, json

Hello I want to remove part of the name of all keys in my json dictionary

so what I did is that I generated the names of the files first

```
def list_of_files():
    path = '/mnt/c/Users/base'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for f in files:
        print(files)
        return files
```

The result

```
['test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt']
```

After that, I loaded the files

```
def load_file(filename):
    loadfile = open("'/base'"+ filename, "r")
        return(loadfile)
```

Then I looped through the file names and attached the contents in a json dictionary

```
a = list_of_files()

data2 = { i : load_file(i) for i in a }
```

Then I put all in a json dictionary

```
{
"test1.txt": [
            "example 1",
             "Example 2"
             ],

"test2.txt": [
            "example 1",
             "Example 2"
             ],

"test3.txt": [
            "example 1",
             "Example 2"]
}
```

I want the output to be the name of the files less the extension(.txt)

```
{
"test1": [
            "example 1",
             "Example 2"
             ],

"test2": [
            "example 1",
             "Example 2"
             ],

"test3": [
            "example 1",
             "Example 2"]
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: from where `["example 1",  "Example 2"]` coming from ?

Comment: You can remove the `.txt` _when you're creating the dictionary_ in the dict comprehension

Comment: from where ["example 1",  "Example 2"] >This was the contents of the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
data2 = { i[:-4] : load_file(i) for i in a }
```

would do that?